# XOR pixel by pixel of two image in python

Tags: python, image

XOR of two images `img1` and `img2` gives a new image `dst`, as in the code below:

```py
import cv2

img1 = cv2.imread('i.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('j.jpg')

dst = cv2.bitwise_xor(img1, img2)

cv2.imwrite('m.jpg', dst)
```

But when I XOR `img1` and `dst` it doesn't give `img2` as one would expect.

Also, what's the best way to XOR two images pixel by pixel in python?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the result instead? Logic seems straight forward here

Comment: @Eliahu But It is true for .png file.

Comment: @mrythm: I just help editing the question to make it more clear and help you get an answer. I did not attempt to answer. You can edit it your self to clarify and add details.